# Exp:resso store add item to cart on load

Tags: expresso-store

So I have a part of a site we are working on that has some unusual needs for checkout that I'm wondering how best to accomplish.  It's an online application with an application fee at the end of the process.  The application is all powered by channel:form and what we are hoping to do is have the last page of the form be a credit card form.  We can't figure out how to do a checkout without having them go through an "add to cart" type step?

We have two channels, applications and products, and we made a product called "application fee" but can't figure out how to add it to a cart automatically?

The second part of the question is that ideally after they pay for an item it would update the application's status field...

Are either of these two things possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several answers on this site that will help with adding a product to the cart.

1. This one is for a single page donate process:
   https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/11037/28
2. This one is for adding to the cart using Ajax:
   https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/6086/28
3. Another using Ajax:
   https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/11607/28

---

A couple options for changing the status after payment is complete:

1. Build an Extension using the Exp:resso Store `store_order_complete_end` hook:
   https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#store_order_complete_end
2. Add channel:form to the order "success page" and set the status in a hidden input... then submit the form using Ajax.